# user1 send msg to user2 it received ,its not coming while user2 sends to user1 (node, react and socket-io)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, mern, messaging

i have set up a node server with socket io here is my backend.

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
global.onlineUsers = new Map();
const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      credentials: true,
    },
  });

io.on("connection", socketConnection);
```

and here is socketConnection fn.

```
 const socketConnection =  (socket) => {
    global.globalSocket = socket;
    globalSocket.on("add-user", socketEvents['add-user']);
    globalSocket.on("remove-user", socketEvents['remove-user']);
    globalSocket.on("user-reConnected", socketEvents['user-reConnected']);
    globalSocket.on("send-msg",socketEvents['send-msg'] );
    globalSocket.on("msg-seen",socketEvents['msg-seen'] );
}
```

here is my socket event fn.

```
 const socketEvents = {
    "add-user": ({ownId,id}) => {
        if(ownId && id){
            console.log("user connected",ownId)
            onlineUsers.set(ownId, id);
            console.log("user added",onlineUsers)
        }
    },
    "send-msg" : (data) => {
        eventEmitter.emit('addSenderUserList',data);
        const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to);
        if (sendUserSocket) {
            let obj = {fromSelf:false,message:data.chat,recieverId:    data.to,sender:data.from,time:data.date}
            globalSocket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-recieve", obj);
            eventEmitter.emit('addRecieverUserList',data);
        }
    }
}
```

and now i am sharing my client side code. this is  APP.JS

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { SERVER } from "./server/server";
 
export const SOCKET = io(SERVER);

function App() {
  const {ownId,ownName} = useOwnIdentity(); // hook which gives loggedIn user creden..
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function O_messageRecieved ({fromSelf,message,recieverId,sender,time}) {
   // update the message ARRAY 
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
      SOCKET.on("msg-recieve",O_messageRecieved);
    return ()=>{
      SOCKET.off("msg-recieve")
    }
  },[global.ACTIVE_USER])  // while selecting any user to chat i set globally
  return (...any-component)
}
```

i am calling msg emit event from other component in which i import SOCKET from APP.js and then i am calling like this.

```
 const handleSendMsg = async (chat) => {  // calling when click on send btn.
      dispatch({   // updating the message ARRAY
        type:'GET_USER_MSG_BY_SOCKET',
        payload:{..typed-msg}
    })
      SOCKET.timeout(500).emit("send-msg",{
        to: global.ACTIVE_USER,
        from: ownId,
        chat,
        date: Date.now(),
      },async()=>{
        await axios.post(`${SERVER}/messages/sendMsg`, {  // for DB
          from: ownId,
          to: global.ACTIVE_USER,
          message: chat,
        });
      });
  
  };
```

and for logout operation which is performing in other component where i import SOCKET from APP.js i use like this .

```
 const logOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    SOCKET.emit("remove-user", ownId);
    navigate("/");
  };
```

actually i am tired of trying 24*7 , not solved the issue, after implementation i successfully connected both the user , means i added in onlineUser object, and when i send message from user1 to user2 , it works perfectly , but when i send message from user2 to user1 , the SOCKET.on('msg-recieve') is not working, i am not getting message from user2 to user1 , while it works perfect when i send msg from user1 to user2. Even i cross verify with each user socketId , while emit message from backend and front as well, it matched. please help me what to do...